# Flink pattern getting issue with Arralist in alert code?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I followed [this example](https://resources.oreilly.com/examples/9781786466228/blob/ab9dd42822f344edeb6d9e5f42bb335ba49fbc5d/MasteringApacheFlink_Code/Chapter05/src/main/java/com/demo/chapter05/KafkaApp.java) and implemented with kafka json same sample data.

consumer sample data `{"temperature" : 28,"machineName":"xyz"}`

```
DataStream<Alert> patternStream = CEP.pattern(inputEventStream, warningPattern)
        .flatSelect(new PatternFlatSelectFunction<TemperatureEvent, Alert>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


        @Override
        public void flatSelect(Map<String, List<TemperatureEvent>> event, Collector<Alert> out) throws Exception {
            new Alert("Temperature Rise Detected:" + ((TemperatureEvent) event.get("first")).getTemperature()
                    + " on machine name:" + ((MonitoringEvent) event.get("first")).getMachineName());

        }
```

Now i am getting issue with ArrayList cast

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:146)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniCluster.executeJobBlocking(MiniCluster.java:647)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.LocalStreamEnvironment.execute(LocalStreamEnvironment.java:123)
at Test.KafkaApp.main(KafkaApp.java:61)
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to Test.TemperatureEvent
    at Test.KafkaApp$2.flatSelect(KafkaApp.java:53)
    at org.apache.flink.cep.operator.FlatSelectCepOperator.processMatchedSequences(FlatSelectCepOperator.java:66)
    at org.apache.flink.cep.operator.AbstractKeyedCEPPatternOperator.processEvent(AbstractKeyedCEPPatternOperator.java:382)
    at org.apache.flink.cep.operator.AbstractKeyedCEPPatternOperator.processElement(AbstractKeyedCEPPatternOperator.java:198)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamInputProcessor.processInput(StreamInputProcessor.java:202)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OneInputStreamTask.run(OneInputStreamTask.java:105)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:300)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:704)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Could you show the codes of inputStream?

Comment: DataStream<TemperatureEvent> inputEventStream = env.addSource(
   new FlinkKafkaConsumer<TemperatureEvent>("demo", new EventDeserializationSchema(), properties));

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains two problems:

- First of all `flatSelect` receives a `Map<String, List<TemperatureEvent>>`. This means that you get potentially multiple `TemperatureEvents` per pattern. Thus, you have to select which one you want.
- You don't add any `Alerts` to the `Collector<Alert>`. A flat map function does not return values but outputs them via a `Collector<Alert>`

Without compiling, I think this should do the trick

```
DataStream<Alert> patternStream = CEP.pattern(inputEventStream, warningPattern)
    .flatSelect(
    new PatternFlatSelectFunction<TemperatureEvent, Alert>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void flatSelect(Map<String, List<TemperatureEvent>> event, Collector<Alert> out) throws Exception {
            TemperatureEvent temperatureEvent = event.get("first").get(0);
            out.collect(new Alert("Temperature Rise Detected:" + temperatureEvent.getTemperature() + " on machine name:" + temperatureEvent.getMachineName()));
        }
       });
```

By the way, the linked code from the O'Reilly repository won't compile with Flink. The `PatternSelectFunction` has the wrong signature.

Comment: but its getting issue with casting

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to Test.TemperatureEvent
 at Test.KafkaApp$2.flatSelect(KafkaApp.java:53)
 at org.apache.flink.cep.operator.FlatSelectCepOperator.processMatchedSequences(FlatSelectCepOperator.java:66)
 at org.apache.flink.cep.operator.AbstractKeyedCEPPatternOperator.processEvent(AbstractKeyedCEPPatternOperator.java:382)
 at org.apache.flink.cep.operator.Abs

Comment: I'm not doing the cast in my code. Which code did you try out?

Comment: DataStream<Alert> patternStream = CEP.pattern(inputEventStream, warningPattern)
   .select(new PatternSelectFunction<TemperatureEvent, Alert>() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
   public Alert select(Map<String, TemperatureEvent> event) throws Exception {
    return new Alert("Temperature Rise Detected:" + ((TemperatureEvent) event.get("first")).getTemperature()
      + " on machine name:" + ((MonitoringEvent) event.get("first")).getMachineName());
   }

Comment: As I've written above the signature of the `PatternSelectFunction<TemperatureEvent, Alert>#select` is `Alert select(Map<String, List<TemperatureEvent> events)` and not `Alert select(Map<String, TemperatureEvent> event)`. Please also make sure that you use the same Flink version as dependency and for the cluster.

Comment: Yes , same thing i have changed the signature what ever you suggested but its getting ArrayList can not be cast issue

Comment: "  @Override
   public Alert select(Map<String, List<TemperatureEvent>> event) throws Exception {
    return new Alert("Temperature Rise Detected:" + ((TemperatureEvent) event.get("first")).getTemperature()
      + " on machine name:" + ((MonitoringEvent) event.get("first")).getMachineName());
   }"

Comment: Could you share a link to a Github repo with your code so that I can take a look at the problem?

Comment: Sure. Thank you

Comment: The code you've shared with me compiles and seems to work. Not sure whether I understand what exactly your problem is.

Comment: It's not getting any alert message

Comment: Have you checked your input? Has the Kafka topic the required messages enqueued?

Comment: data {"temperature" : 28,"machineName":"xyz"}

Comment: Finally it works. Issue with Eventdeserialization getting array index out of bound